# Scrapy: Using FTP with XmlItemExporter

Tags: python, scrapy

I wrote a custom pipeline to get the node names that I wanted:

```
class XmlExportPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):

         pipeline = cls()
         crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
         crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
         return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        file = open('crawl.xml', 'w',encoding='utf-8')
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporter = XmlItemExporter(file,item_element='job', root_element='jobs', indent=1)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()


    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        file = self.files.pop(spider)
        file.close()
        self.uploadftp(spider)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

Now I can't figure out how to export with FTP instead of just local storage.

Comment: Do you know about [feed exports](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html)? If so, what prevents you from using them for FTP exporting?

Comment: I do know feed exports, but I wanted to format the xml with custom node/root names, and the internet then told me to use a custom pipeline instead.

Answer (score 0):

To change item data, pipelines are great. And there are indeed export use cases where they also make sense (e.g. [splitting items across multiple files](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#using-item-exporters)).

To change the output format, however, it may be better to implement a custom feed exporter, register it in [`FEED_EXPORTERS`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-exporters) and enable it in [`FEED_FORMAT`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std:setting-FEED_FORMAT).

There’s no extensive documentation about creating custom feed exporters, but if you have a look at the implementation of [`XmlItemExporter`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.exporters.XmlItemExporter) you should be able to figure things out.

In fact, looking at your code and [`XmlItemExporter`’s](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/exporters.py#L134) you may simply need to subclass [`XmlItemExporter`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.exporters.XmlItemExporter), change its `__init__` method to pass `item_element='job', root_element='jobs'` to the parent `__init__`, and use the [`FEED_EXPORT_INDENT`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-export-indent) setting to define the desired indentation (`1`).

Comment: [Hopefully](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/3858/files#r326850736), in the future all this can also be achieved using the [proposed `FEEDS` setting](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/3858).